# Should I ask if I don't expect an answer here?

Tags: discussion

For question that are local to my region, but not too localised to be on-topic, I know that I'll get a good answer at the Swedish language forum [utsidan](http://www.utsidan.se).  The chance that I get a good answer here at this stage is very small.  Should I still ask?

I could ask here in English, there in Swedish, then post a translation/summary of the answer from there, here, but I'm not sure if this is good etiquette.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you should.

If you can, at a later point, answer your own question and document it the better.

Comment: I agree. Also adds more data here which will lead people here through search engines.